# How to import rules.csv to sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a rules.csv file which I downloaded from another site, how do I import this to my sonar?

I do not have the credentials to get the XML file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i figure it out. if you MUST get the rules from another group then do this:

1. click configuration and choose the quality profile
2. click the permalink tab
3. copy the xml of all the rules you wanted, save them accordlying
4. create a new profile and use those files you saved as the new rules

Comment: what if i want to import rules for PHP language?? do you have any idea reagarding this

Answer (score 4):

you cannot import a CSV file into Sonar. You can only import XML backups for quality profiles, or XML rulesets files for specific tools (Checkstyle, PMD, ...)

CSV is just a way to export rules, but not to import them.

Comment: Fabrice, can you explain how can i import .xml files of Checkstyle and pmd to sonar?

Comment: is there any way to import CodeSniffer file for PHP projects