# Sonar Quality Profile for JavaScript is Empty

Tags: sonarqube

Quick question with regards to Sonar and JavaScript.  I was able to get examples of JsTestDriver and Jasmine working with Maven - Hudson - Sonar (code coverage and tests).  The only piece I am missing is the rules violations report.  When I look at sonarsource's doc/post on the JavaScript plugin, it says that it comes with 60 default rules.  But when I install the SonarQube JavaScript plugin and then go into my Quality Profiles (selecting the "Sonar way"), there are no rules within this profile.  I assume this is why I am not seeing metrics produced within my project and so I was wondering does the SonarQube JavaScript plugin come with the 60 default rules described within the sonarsource site?  Or do I need to create all my JavaScript rules?

Comment: I confirm that they're shipped with the plugin. What are your versions of SonarQube and the JavaScript plugin? Are you sure that you cannot activate them from the Quality Profiles page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles ?

Comment: Version 3.7.1 of SonarQube and JavaScript 1.4.  I was able to solve it based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283868/how-do-i-import-rules-csv-to-sonar, by going to http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/120?searchtext=&plugins[]=&priorities[]=&rule_status=&commit=Search permalink and saving off the xml, then restoring the Quality Profile (by deleting and restoring Sonar Way for JavaScript).  Now I have the 60 rules.